# Urdu values from text field and how can i insert in database?

Tags: mysql, database, c#-4.0

```
 string query3 = "INSERT INTO library_database.status_of_issue VALUES('";
                            query3 = query3 + textBox2.Text + "','";
                            query3 = query3 + textBox1.Text + "', CURDATE(),ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY))";
                            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query3, con);
```

text feild should received urdu text whenever from open . and how can i add urdu value in my database? how can insert urdu text from textfield to in my mysql database. there is some query problem with me how can i write my query?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide what the error you are getting  ? I suggest you first write the insert statement using your SQL and check . I think the Insert statement should be as

```
var text1 = query3 + textbox2.Text;
var text2 = query3 + textbox1.Text;

= "INSERT INTO library_database.status_of_issue VALUES('"+text1 +"','"+text2 +"',CURDATE(),ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY))";
```

If this also doesnt work, request you to provide your SQL table schema of "library_database.status_of_issue".

Hope your field in which you are trying to insert the urdu text is of type : nvarchar
Then you can also insert as below :

```
insert into [library_database.status_of_issue] ([fieldname]) values ('N'@urduvalue)
```

Comment: actually i am using varchar type of field and manully it allows to insert urdu text but when i add it by form then ???? value are inserted in the table fields @adityaaswami

Comment: Did you try the above method ?? just copy the insert statement into your form insert code and check . It should work !!!

Comment: Yes i check it but its now working in the mysql and also  when i insert it manually with out any query its adds properly.

Comment: Make a SQLParameter and then pass it on to your SQLCommand object, and specify the DB type of this SQL Parameter to be of nvarchar type.

Comment: kindly give me some code so i can i add it in my project as i am new and i dont know how sql parameter pass?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please mark as answered, if it answers you question .